# Encrypt empty string

Tags: ruby, ssl, encryption, openssl, aes

I am using Ruby's [Open SSL bindings](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/OpenSSL.html) to do AES-256 encryption.  I can encrypt a non-empty string.  However, when attempting to encrypt an empty string, Ruby raises an exception complaining that the data must not be empty.  **How can I encrypt an empty string using Ruby's OpenSSL bindings?**

## Code to reproduce the problem

```
require "openssl"

KEY = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc").random_key

def encrypt(plaintext)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
  cipher.encrypt
  iv = cipher.random_iv
  cipher.iv = iv
  cipher.key = KEY
  ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext)    # <- ArgumentError here
  ciphertext << cipher.final
  [iv, ciphertext]
end

def decrypt(iv, ciphertext)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
  cipher.decrypt
  cipher.iv = iv
  cipher.key = KEY
  plaintext = cipher.update(ciphertext)
  plaintext << cipher.final
  plaintext
end

p decrypt(*encrypt("foo"))    # "foo"

p decrypt(*encrypt(""))
# /tmp/foo.rb:11:in `update': data must not be empty (ArgumentError)
#         from /tmp/foo.rb:11:in `encrypt'
#         from /tmp/foo.rb:27:in `<main>'
```

## Versions

- ruby-2.2.2p95
- OpenSSL::VERSION is "1.1.0"
- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8)

## Why do I want to encrypt empty strings?

I am writing an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) program to migrate data from one database to a SqlServer database.  Certain columns from the source database must be encrypted before writing them to the destination database.  The source columns may contain any data, including empty strings.  The destination columns are usually non-nullable.  The destination columns will be decrypted by .net code.

Goal #1: No information about the encrypted field, including whether or not it even exists, should be recoverable without properly decrypting it.  An encrypted empty string should be indistinguishable from any other encrypted data.

Goal #2: The .net code that will decrypt these values should not need to handle empty strings specially.

If I can get openssl to encrypt empty strings, I will achieve both of these goals.

## Workaround - Don't encrypt empty strings

I could just not encrypt empty strings, passing them through.

```
def encrypt(plaintext)
  return plaintext if plaintext.empty?
  ...
end

def decrypt(iv, ciphertext)
  return ciphertext if ciphertext.empty?
  ...
end
```

This has the disadvantages of exposing information, and also of requiring cooperating code to be written on the .net side.

## Workaround - Add some constant to the plaintext

I could add some constant string to the plaintext before encryption, and remove it after decryption:

```
PLAINTEXT_SUFFIX = " "

def encrypt(plaintext)
  plaintext += PLAINTEXT_SUFFIX
  ...
end

def decrypt(iv, ciphertext)
  ...
  plaintext.chomp(PLAINTEXT_SUFFIX)
end
```

This hides whether the data exists or not, but still requires cooperating .net code.

Comment: OpenSSL supports PKCS#7 padding, so this should work. This is probably better suited as a bug report. Btw, have you tried simply skipping `cipher.update` if the plaintext is empty? `cipher.final` might be sufficient in that case.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I had tried omitting the call to Cipher#update.  It didn't work when I tried it earlier due to an ID10T error than I didn't notice at the time.  It turns that's the solution.  Would you mind please adding it as an answer?

Comment: You can add it yourself. I have no idea about ruby and I don't want to start learning at this particular time. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As suggested by @ArtjomB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068856/encrypt-empty-string#comment57865596_35068856), it's as simple as not calling [`Cipher#update`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-update) with the empty string.  The value returned by [`Cipher#final`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-final) then properly encrypts an empty string.

```
require "openssl"

KEY = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc").random_key

def encrypt(plaintext)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
  cipher.encrypt
  iv = cipher.random_iv
  cipher.iv = iv
  cipher.key = KEY
  ciphertext = ""
  ciphertext << cipher.update(plaintext) unless plaintext.empty?
  ciphertext << cipher.final
  [iv, ciphertext]
end

def decrypt(iv, ciphertext)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
  cipher.decrypt
  cipher.iv = iv
  cipher.key = KEY
  plaintext = cipher.update(ciphertext)
  plaintext << cipher.final
end

p decrypt(*encrypt("foo"))    # "foo"
p decrypt(*encrypt(""))       # ""
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use DBMS provided encryption functions, then, MySQL [`AES_ENCRYPT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt), seems to be able to encrypt blank string.

For example:

```
UPDATE some_table 
   SET some_column =  AES_ENCRYPT('',UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3'));
```

It's AES-128 by default, I am guessing that will be a problem as you need AES-256.  Also, not sure which DBMS you are using and whether that DBMS has encryption functions.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the database to do the encryption.  The destination DB is SqlServer 2014.

Comment: @WayneConrad Don't know much about that server, but it seems to have AES-256 encryption support.  You may have to test it out for blank string encryption.

Comment: @WayneConrad  On a side note, because of  your SO profile page - I discovered that there was something called [Ruby Extensions](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html) that had first versions of `Symbol#to_proc`, that got assimilated in Rails and then to Ruby core.  I was doing some investigation about whether you really used `[day, dollar].each(&:another)` in 2003. :D

Comment: _Excellent_ catch.  In 2003, I was using (I think) Ruby 1.6.  In the interest of accuracy, I've updated my profile.